# "Incorrect syntax near '='." Delet

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a question, I want to delete in database but I get error:

```
private int db_execute(string sql_text)
{
        string cn_string = Properties.Settings.Default.Fahrzeug_DatenbankConnectionString;
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cn_string);

        if(cn.State != ConnectionState.Open) cn.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter sql_adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(sql_text, cn);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cn_string,cn);

        int intresult = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();

        return intresult;
}

private void Delete_Loaded_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Delet();
}

private void Delet()
{
    Fahrzeug row = mainGrid.SelectedItem as Fahrzeug;

    string FahrzeugName = row.Name.ToString();
    string FahrzeugTyp = row.Typ.ToString();
    int FahrzeugBaujahr = int.Parse(row.Jahr.ToString());

    string sql_text = "DELETE FROM Bericht_Table WHERE Name=" + this.NameEingabe.Text.ToString();
    db_execute(sql_text);

    LadeAusDerDatenbank();
}
```

This is the error I get:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "Incorrect syntax near '='

Comment: Yeah, look at the accurate syntax for the DELETE FROM SQL command. Interwebs is full with guides/tutorials/examples. Random pick: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp . Pay attention to every single character that is necessary to form such a DELETE FROM command, especially if your WHERE clause contains text/string values. Then take a stern, careful and attentive look at the content of your `sql_text` variable and you should notice where it is not following the correct syntax for the DELETE FROM command.

Comment: I have already tried but do not know what the problem is?                                                      Fahrzeug row = mainGrid.SelectedItem as Fahrzeug;
          
            string FahrzeugName = row.Name.ToString();

            string FahrzeugTyp = row.Typ.ToString();

            int FahrzeugBaujahr = int.Parse(row.Jahr.ToString());                           string sql_text = "DELETE FROM Bericht_Table WHERE Name ='"+FahrzeugName+"'";

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but do you have quotes around the name so the string becomes valid i.e. 
`"DELETE FROM Bericht_Table WHERE Name=\""+this.NameEingabe.Text.ToString()+"\"";